# Issue storing a value in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a GPO which will run on servers.
In the batch, I've set the variable `SourcePath=%~0\..` which works nicely to allow me to access files from the same location as that which the batch itself is running from.

```
%sourcepath%\Sigcheck\sigcheck.exe /accepteula -q -n "c:\path\file.exe" >fileversion
set /p filever= < fileversion
```

This code works nicely to check the version of a file `file.exe` putting it into `fileversion`.
`fileversion` is then read into the variable `filever`.

So this code does everything I want it to do but there's a problem. A file called `fileversion` gets created in the GPO folder (`%sourcepath%`). This would be okay except if multiple servers are executing the batch at the same time they would all try to create this file at the same time and possibly overwrite the file or cause errors. Once the value is read into the variable `filever`, it is no longer needed but deleting it is not enough because two systems should be able to execute the script at the same time.

Is there another way to capture the value into a variable that wont have this issue? I thought about putting a local path in front of `fileversion` so it's stored locally but I am not keen on this option.

Comment: %~0 is the path AND FILENAME to your batch file.  I am surprised that this works.  %~DP0 is the path to the batch file without the name of the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a file then, use a `FOR /F` loop instead to read the output of the command directly. Here's an example:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN (
  '%sourcepath%\Sigcheck\sigcheck.exe /accepteula -q -n "c:\path\file.exe"'
) DO (
  SET "filever=%%L"
)
```

The single quotes denote a command to run and read the output of. After running the command, its output is iterated over by the loop line by line.

If the output consists of just one line, the above will be enough: the variable gets assigned and the loop terminates. If there may be more lines (and you want to remember only the first one and prevent other lines from overwriting the first value), you have at least two options:

1. store the value only if the variable is not already set (defined):

```
SET filever=
FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN (
  '%sourcepath%\Sigcheck\sigcheck.exe /accepteula -q -n "c:\path\file.exe"'
) DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED filever SET "filever=%%L"
)
```

Note that the variable needs to be unset first (the first line).

2. store the the value and jump outside the loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%L IN (
  '%sourcepath%\Sigcheck\sigcheck.exe /accepteula -q -n "c:\path\file.exe"'
) DO (
  SET "filever=%%L"
  GOTO out
)

:out
```

This remembers the first line and forces exiting the loop, to prevent iterating over other lines.

You can read more about the `FOR /F` loop in the built-in help (`FOR /?` or `HELP FOR`).

Comment: Hey @mathijsuitmegen, that was a good catch. I didn't realise the output redirection not only would cause a syntax error there but also was completely unnecessary. Thanks for the edit, cheers.